# Protobuf causes segmentation fault on ParseFromIstream

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to expand my programming knowledge, and I trying to do some multi-process programming.

I would like to do the following: on the same host, multiple executables are run. One of the executables is responsible for scanning the filesystem, one of the executables is processing data etc.

However, some of the data has to be transferred off-host. To limit things like network firewall settings, I would like to have a single daemon (multi-threaded) to receive the data via IPC, before sending it onward to an external host using a not-yet determined socket implementation.

After doing a lot of searching and research, the most obvious pattern to use is the consumer / producer pattern, with multi-process producers (the daemons producing messages) and a multi-threaded consumer (receiving data, preferably via shared memory, and sending it to an external host).

I want my application to be able to run cross-platform as much as possible. To this end, I am using boost::interprocess:message_queue. Because this Boost library only accepts binary serialized objects, I am using Google Protobuf to handle serialization and deserialization.

I created 2 executables, currently called "consumer" and "producer". The producer sends the message via the message queue to the consumer, which in turn deserializes it. The code below works when passing simple "int" objects (which, in my mind, means that the message queue communication is working), but does not work when using data from SerializeToOstream().

As you may have noticed, I am a novice at IPC and multi-process programming, but I believe I've done my homework.

Here is my producer.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <internal/messages/testmessage.pb.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Construct the object to be passed
    GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

    struct protoremove {
        ~protoremove(){ google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary(); }
    } remover;

    ib::protobuf::testMessage myMessage;
    myMessage.set_id(10);
    myMessage.set_version(1);
    std::cout << myMessage.DebugString() << std::endl;

    // Initialize the Boost message queue
    try{
        //Open a message queue.
        boost::interprocess::message_queue mq
                (boost::interprocess::open_or_create
                        ,"message_queue"           //name
                        ,100                       //max message number
                        ,1000               //max message size
                );

        // Send our message
        std::ofstream buftosend;
        myMessage.SerializeToOstream(&buftosend);
        mq.send(&buftosend, sizeof(buftosend), 1);

    }
    catch(boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception &ex){
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The consumer.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <internal/messages/testmessage.pb.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Open the message queue
    try {
        //Erase previous message queue
        boost::interprocess::message_queue::remove("message_queue");
        ib::protobuf::testMessage recvdMessage;

        //Create a message_queue.
        boost::interprocess::message_queue mq
                (boost::interprocess::open_or_create
                        ,"message_queue"           //name
                        ,100                       //max message number
                        ,1000               //max message size
                );

        unsigned int priority;
        boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;

        std::ifstream incomingbuf;
        mq.receive(&incomingbuf, 1000, recvd_size, priority);

        recvdMessage.ParseFromIstream(&incomingbuf);

        recvdMessage.id();
        recvdMessage.DebugString();
    }
    catch(boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception &ex){
        boost::interprocess::message_queue::remove("message_queue");
        std::cout << "IP error " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    boost::interprocess::message_queue::remove("message_queue");
    return 0;

}
```

And the message definition (.proto):

```
package ib.protobuf;

message testMessage {
    required int32 version = 1;
    optional int64 id = 2;
    optional string data = 3;
    optional int64 sequencenumber = 4;
}
```

When running consumer, it waits for data (the mq.receive() call is blocking).
When producer starts, consumer gets a SIGSEGV. gdb indicates in its backtrace that this is happening on line 44, which is the ParseFromIstream() method.
Producer outputs the correct values in DebugString().

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/roel/bin/consumer 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
std::istream::sentry::sentry (this=0x7fffffffe117, __in=..., __noskip=true)
    at /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc:50
50  /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  std::istream::sentry::sentry (this=0x7fffffffe117, __in=..., __noskip=true)
    at /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc:50
#1  0x00007ffff679f7ab in std::istream::read (this=0x7fffffffe380, 
    __s=0x637d20 "", __n=8192)
    at /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc:653
#2  0x00007ffff6b10030 in google::protobuf::io::IstreamInputStream::CopyingIstreamInputStream::Read(void*, int) () from /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.9
#3  0x00007ffff6a99fe1 in google::protobuf::io::CopyingInputStreamAdaptor::Next(void const**, int*) () from /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.9
#4  0x00007ffff6a97950 in google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::Refresh() ()
   from /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.9
#5  0x00007ffff6a94da3 in google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromZeroCopyStream(google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream*) () from /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.9
#6  0x00007ffff6af5ad9 in google::protobuf::Message::ParseFromIstream(std::istream*) () from /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.9
#7  0x0000000000407e35 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe6d8)
    at /home/roel/source/consumer.cpp:44
(gdb)
```

This is compiled on Linux using CMake and GCC 6.0.1. 
I have a number of questions about my program:

---

**`Q1.`** First and foremost; **what could be causing the segmentation fault?**
What am I doing wrong? I've looked at this code for many hours, but cannot see the issue.

---

**`Q2.`** In the boost::interprocess::message_queue
    constructor, I have to define 2 parameters; the maximum number of
    messages, as well as the size. For standard types, this size is
    fixed. However, with messages (in general), the size of the message
    is variable. So, **what would be the best way to determine the amount
    of memory to be reserved for messages?** Should I simply set a maximum
    size per message and create some multi-part message parameter?

---

**`Q3.`** **Is there a better way of accomplishing my goal?** Serializing data,
    putting it into a queue just seems so.. complicated, especially
    seeing this is probably a very common problem. There must be more
    people trying to create cross-platform IPC. Libraries like ZeroMQ
    only support UNIX domain sockets. Using TCP sockets to the loopback
    interface just seems ugly. Isn't there simply a library that lets me
    put arbitrary objects (size and layout) as messages in a shared
    memory segment, which a consumer can then `pop()`? I mean, within a
    single thread, this can be fixed by `push()` and `pop()` on the stack.
    Doing all these extra steps seems like a lot of overhead.

Thank you in advance for any response.

---

### Edit

As The Dark notes, the code above is using an instance of `std::string` instead of the actual string `(std::string.data())`

producer.cpp is answered below:

```
std::string str = myMessage.SerializeAsString();
mq.send(str.data(), str.size(), 1);
```

However, this does not work as-is for consumer.cpp, as strings are initialized with a size of 0.

Here is the code I used for consumer.cpp:

```
unsigned int priority;
boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;

//Reserve 1000 bytes of memory for our message
char incomingBuffer[1000];
mq.receive(&incomingBuffer, 1000, recvd_size, priority);

ib::protobuf::testMessage recvdMessage;

//Only if string object is really required
std::basic_string<char> str = incomingBuffer;
std::cout << "Message: " << str.data() << ". Size is " << recvd_size << std::endl;

//ParseFromString() can also directly parse "incomingBuffer", avoiding the cast above
recvdMessage.ParseFromString(str.data());

std::cout << "Message ID " << recvdMessage.id() << std::endl;
std::cout << recvdMessage.DebugString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the producer seems wrong.

```
    // Send our message
    std::ofstream buftosend;
    myMessage.SerializeToOstream(&buftosend);
    mq.send(&buftosend, sizeof(buftosend), 1);
```

The `ofstream` has not been opened and so does not have a file to store anything, so the first call will fail (not crash). The send call is sending the raw `ofstream` class structure across the line. This will not be in a transmittable format.

I think what you want is to serialize to an ostringstream, then transmit the contents of the ostringstream (not the whole object).

Something like:

```
    // Send our message
    std::ostringstream buftosend;
    myMessage.SerializeToOstream(&buftosend);
    std::string str = buftosend.str();
    mq.send(str.data(), str.size(), 1);
```

Or better yet:

```
    // Send our message
    std::string str = myMessage.SerializeAsString();
    mq.send(str.data(), str.size(), 1);
```

You can also add a debug line to show what is the contents of `str`, though note it will be binary so not legible.

You may have a similar issue with your consumer (ifstream needs to be opened on a file).

Comment: Thank you. Took me a little time to read up on the differences between ostream, ofstream and ostringstream, but I think I got it.

I edited the topic above with the solution for consumer.cpp, as it is too long for a comment.

If you have any insights into my other questions, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**`A3:`**

### **`ZeroMQ`**

As far as `ZeroMQ` is concerned, there are **many different** transport-classes available that can be used at the same time. So should one wishes to use the lowest-overhead for local inter-thread signalling, there we go with **`inproc://`** transport-class, if going local inter-process, one may `.bind()` / `.connect()` using **`ipc://`** transport-class. For inter-platform distributed processing, the **`tcp://`** or **`pgm://`** or **`epgm://`** transport-classes make the choice easy with respect to the communication needs aligned with the system and networking capabilities.

<sub>( [Do not hesitate to check other posts, with also a direct URL to **Pieter HINTJENS' book, a must-read** for going into distributed systems design](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) )</sub>

---

### **`nanomsg`**

Another smart & lightweight broker-less messaging / signalling framework **`nanomsg`** comes from Martin SUSTRIK, the co-father of `ZeroMQ`. Again, **`INPROC`**, **`IPC`**, and **`TCP`**, transport classes are ready. [Definitely worth a few minutes to read his **insightfull remarks on this subject.**](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html)

---

Using these frameworks however relies, due to reasonable assumption that messaging agent has no clue what system is standing on the remote end of the messaging/signalling socket, on some sort of object-representation -- be it called serialisation, containerised object, object-wrapper, simply one bears the responsibility to "prepare" an object of one's wish into a transportable fashion for both the dispatch and remote re-instatement.

Using a generalised shared-memory design, as was asked, goes into other architecture, whereas the `ZeroMQ` **`inproc://`** and `nanomsg` **`INPROC`**  transport-classes are **Zero-Copy** almost-**Zero-Latency** examples for this general idea.

Comment: Zero and nanomsg were acruelly my first choice when researching. Unfortunately, IPC transport is only supported on systems with UNIX domain sockets, which kind of rules out a major OS (Windows). I do like zeromq though. Nanomsg seemed to be a (for lack of a better word) good fork of 0mq, but has been dead for a while now. Thank you for taking the time to answer though.